# Why isn't my old hard drive connecting to my new computer?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I recently got a new computer, and I'm trying to hook up my old hard drive and SSD to the new one to transfer my data.  It's a prebuilt and I can't figure out how to install them directly.

I got a SATA to USB cable, and plugged in the hard drive as shown in the image [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IGaN.jpg).  It lights up like it thinks it's working, but my computer can't seem to find my drive.

When I plug in my SSD it works, but experiences frequent disconnections even with the power supply setting toggled. Is it like a loose connection? Can the USB not handle that much power? Why don't the HDDs work when the SSD does, and why does the cable indicate it's figured it out?

Comment: I can't tell by the picture.. is that a 3.5 inch hdd or a 2.5 inch?  The power draw is very different between the two.  Also, the power provided by USB2 is MUCH MUCH lower than USB3.  It would help us out to know more specs.. and for myself.. I have several USB to 2.5 inch sata adapters that work fine without additional power.. I have never seen a 3.5 inch drive that didn't need an enclosure without additional power.  Your SSD should work fine right off of the USB port (from my experience).

Comment: How is the power supplied to the HDD? From the USB connector alone? Is it regular USB, or USB-C?

Comment: Looks like a 3.5 Inch drive. Which might draw 10-15W at start up. And USB2 supplied power is indeed barely enough for most 2.5 inch drives. USb3 almost doubles that (500mAmp max to 900mAmp)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: 3.5"

Comment: @Justme: Regular USB.  Not sure if it's USB2 or USB3

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @Hennes and JustMe :)  -- Exactly what I was thinking..  You need more juice.  And there is no "regular USB" .. that would be like saying that I have a "regular engine"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard 3.5" HDD needs a 12V supply to spin the motors.

If you only have USB connection, there is no 12V supply provided to the HDD, so it does not work.

2.5" HDDs work with single 5V supply.

Typically adapters intended for use with 3.5" HDD drives come with an external 12V power supply.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this one didn't.  Would that plug into the small plug on the right of the SAT III cable?  How can I find a power supply with the right connector?

Comment: No, the power would be applied to the SATA power connector, but that's integrated to your adapter already. Your adapter already occupies both the SATA power and SATA data signal connectors, so you can't apply external power with that adapter.